# Can you have the name of the arduino pre-defined in the system?

Tags: c#, arduino, arduino-uno

I was developing my project and I ran into a problem! I put my C# program so when a device is connected with the name arduino, the C# program automatically detects that that is the COM input, but I tried it on another computer and when I connect the arduino, the arduino name on windows is not arduino, is there any way any computer can know that the connected device is the arduino when it connects?

[image]

On the other pc the name is "USB Serial Device (COM3), can i pre-define arduino?

Comment: On your PC you have drivers installed and on the other - not. When windows detects device it will use *generic* driver for it, which allows basic/standard functions.

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/a/830730/547545) some more info. Likely you just need to run Windows Update on another PC, though it could be the manufacturer of arduino-uno didn't bother to put his driver there.

Answer (score 3):

I think microsoft has a way you can register your product so they can recognize it. Companies like Logitech use this so when you plug in their mouse the OS can see that device and then recognise it.
The idea is that you pay microsoft to write a handshaking routine for their OS. Then on the next upgrade the feature goes active.

Two problems.
#1 it would cost thousands of dollars for microsoft. Same for apple.
#2 the arduino would have to have the handshaking routine or unique identifier. The added chip would then be required for the handshaking to happen.

So the answer is yes it is possible. But the cost of implementation would be very high and it would require all arduino board makers to buy the chip or add the handshaking routine.